# Laravel 4 HTML images

Tags: php, html, image, laravel, laravel-4

My question is does Laravel accept PNG images or any other format beside JPG. What is happening is when I change my image to JPG it can find it, but as soon as I change it to PNG it no longer can find the image.

```
{{HTML::image('images/DRCSportslogo.png', 'DRC Sports Race Management', array('id' => 'DRCS-logo'));}}
```

I have this image formatted in both PNG and JPG in the same file directory so I know it's not the location of the file.

Comment: As far as I know it shouldn't make a difference. Is the HTML generated correctly? Can you view the source and copy the `src` into your browser and have it load the image correctly?

Comment: Is it case sensitive? Named `.PNG` or something?

Comment: Maybe the permissions to the png file are not correct, the server might not be able to read the .png file.

Answer (score 9):

The laravel search the image in the public folder, then you should have a file public/images/DRCSportslogo.png

```
{{ HTML::image('images/DRCSportslogo.png', $alt="DRCSports", $attributes = array()) }}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
<img src="{{asset('images/DRCSportslogo.png')}}" alt="DRC Sports Race Management" id="DRCS-logo" />
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference what you input there it can be .jpg, .png or even .exe or any other file on system.

You can see that in api page : [L4 API HTML::image](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Html.HtmlBuilder.html#98-111)

Only thing i can suggest is to browse directly to the image you want to reach. In my experience sometimes ftp clients make false uploads (empty png files). That could be the case.

Answer (score -3):

Try giving a permission to the "images" folder

Comment: OP says it works for jpeg, so folder permissions can't be it.